Data Tables Refresh on Edit / Update
In my project, I have been using Data tables to show the list of data from the database per required view.
So in the view, I have this code
<div class="table-responsive mt-4" style="padding-top:50px;">
    <table id="memberList" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee Number</th>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>Designation</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Authorization</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>


the table script
 $('#memberList').DataTable({
     processing: true,
     serverSide: true,
     filter: true,
     scrollY: '400px',
     orderMulti: false,
     ajax: {
         url: getMemberList,
         type: 'POST',
         datatype: 'json'
     },
     columns: [
         { data: "EmpNumber", name: "Employee Number" },
         { data: "EmployeeName", name: "Employee Name" },
         { data: "Dessignation", name: "Designation" },
         { data: "Department", name: "Department" },
         {
             data: "IsAuthorized",
             render: function (data, type, row) {
                 return data
                     ? '<span class="text-success">Allowed</span>'
                     : '<span class="text-danger">Denied</span>';
             },
             name: "Authorization"
         },
         {
             data: "EId",
             render: function (data, type, row) {
                 return `
                 <div class="btn btn-danger delete-member" data-id="${data}">
                     Remove
                 </div>`;
             },
             orderable: false
         }
     ],
     language: {
         search: "Search:"
     }
 });


So in the same view, I have an Add button in which the user selects data from the combo box and clicks the add button then sends that selected value to the controller does the necessary backend process, and saves that on the database table.
Then in the success function, I wanted to refresh the table and I did this
if (response.success) {
  showSuccessToast("Employee added successfully");

  // Refresh the DataTable
  $('#memberList').DataTable().ajax.reload();

  $(ctl).prop("disabled", false).text(originalText);
  closePopup();
}

this did not work and I got an error as
DataTables warning: table id=memberList - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

The error seems clear to me, the json returned from getMemberList is probably incorrect. Did you follow the Diagnose steps in https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1

Set a breakpoint in whatever endpoint server code that getMemberList is pointing at and debug. It's not returning a valid JsonResult.
